# AutoCompleteTextView, DropDown, setOnDismissListener, <17 api

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, dropdown

Please, help

setOnDismissListener is work only on API >=17

How I can detect appears and disappears of AutoCompleteTextView DropDowns in API lower then 17 ?

Comment: What does your code look like? What have you tried? How do you know that `setOnDismissListener` does not work in API>=17?

Answer (score 2):

I have been tested on API Level 16 (works well). But question for Android guru: i think that not so proper method anyway and i look forward to your wise advice:

Put this code to `public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView`

```
public void setupActv() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss() {
                Log.d("testThisShit", "on Dismiss");
            }
        });
    } else {
        try {
            Field popup = AutoCompleteTextView.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
            popup.setAccessible(true);
            ListPopupWindow popupWindow = (ListPopupWindow) popup.get(this);

            popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss() {
                    Log.d("testThisShit", "on Dismiss < 17");
                }
            });

        } catch (NoClassDefFoundError | ClassCastException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.d("testThisShit", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```